# merging values within a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to get `{(A):[12,14]. (B):[3,5], (C,E):[8,2], (D,F):[4,1,3,7]}`

from the dataframe below:

```
class   type    c1   c2   c3  

A        0      12   14  nan
B        1      nan  3    5
C        2      8    nan  2  
D        3      4    1    3
E        2      nan  nan nan
F        3      nan  7   nan
```

I have issues with grouping values on the last columns given the fact that my dataframe can have more columns.

I basically do:

`df.groupby('type')['class'].unique()` to get the list of classes

But I don't manage to get the list of matching values because I have to write a line for each column.

Comment: You can't have lists as keys in dictionaries, are `tuples` OK?

Comment: @user3483203 yes sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick

```py
def process_row(row) : 
    values = [x for y in  list(row.iloc[:,2:].values)  for x in y if not 
               pd.isnull(x)  ]
    return {tuple(row['class']): values}

s = df.groupby('type').apply(process_row)
res = dict()
[res.update(di) for di in s]
print(res)
# {('A',): [12.0, 14.0], ('B',): [3.0, 5.0], ('C', 'E'): [8.0, 2.0], ('D', 'F'): 
# [4.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
def makelist(x):
    return list(x.dropna())

df.groupby('type')\
  .agg({'class':tuple,
        'c1':makelist, 
        'c2':makelist, 
        'c3':makelist})\
  .set_index('class')\
  .sum(axis=1).to_frame()\
  .T.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{('A',): [12.0, 14.0],
  ('B',): [3.0, 5.0],
  ('C', 'E'): [8.0, 2.0],
  ('D', 'F'): [4.0, 1.0, 7.0, 3.0]}]
```